# How to get all implicitly referenced dlls by netcore project?

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, nuget, csproj

**Context**

I am currently developing some sort of ide with extensive code generation, which uses C# as the target language for translation from another high-level language.

**Problem**

Now I am trying to implement an auto-completion feature, like in VisualStudio or rider. But, I stuck with a question - where from could I retrieve available symbols (like classes, struct, namespaces, etc.) which are defined in netcore framework DLL's like mscorlib.dll, System.Data.dll?

I am particularly interested in netcore based projects, which are defined by XML .csproj files.

I am pretty sure that there should be some library/NuGet-package which are made for resolving csproj dependencies and stuff. But it's pretty hard to find because Google results are cluttered with tons of "beginner-friendly" Microsoft manuals, which tell you how to create a new project with dotnet new.

**Input Data**: Let's say we have .csproj like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

There we have two important strings `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"`, which as I understand determines a set of MSBuild-related stuff, like targets, and other stuff.
And `net5.0` which somehow transforms into a reference to some mysterious NuGet meta-package.

There could be some other variation of those two, and these variations lead to different implicitly referenced packages, and I want to know which one exactly.

**Desired output data**

It would be great to have some kind of csproj abstraction, which could provide a list of all dependencies, explicit and implicit, which could be later parsed by Mono.Cecil, and so on.

I know, that there are Roslyn, Nuget, and MsBuild. But which one of them should I use, and how?

Comment: Some semi success findings.
At nuget we have packages called `Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref`, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref`, `icrosoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref`.
They are contains all required for ide compleation feature stuff, like signatures, xml docs, type declarations, etc.. 
Their vesions determines target framework, names are related to target sdk.
This finding kind'a resolves my issue, but this is looks like some hack, and doesn't looks like reliable solution. Because this libs could disapear, if ms again change their mind, about "how things should be done".

Comment: `nuget restore` + `obj/project_assets.json` could be a starting point?